# How do I center Angular Material table column headers and its mat-cell content

Tags: angular, angular-material

can anyone tell me how can i center mat table column headers and its content
here is my html code

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout='column' fxLayoutAlign='center center'>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">


        <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date | date}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

am getting result like this in Small Screen

[image]

and in large screen[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add the following styles to your global `styles.scss` file:

```
th.mat-header-cell,
td.mat-cell {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

[Working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhdccw)

Comment: Doesn't work with 'mat-sort-header '

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous answer, but sticking with flex syntax it would be:

```
th.mat-header-cell,
td.mat-cell {
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```